# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery.min.js:4 [Ajax, jQuery]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I getting this error when my `$.ajax` line runs.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery.min.js:4
e jquery.min.js:4
Vc jquery.min.js:4
Vc jquery.min.js:4
Vc jquery.min.js:4
m.param jquery.min.js:4
m.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:4
ajaxFunction NewHost.php:231
validateInput NewHost.php:324
onclick NewHost.php:114
```

As far as I know the rest of the script works.

I'm changing from using vanilla ajax to jQuery and ajax. The ajax call was adapted from a separate page that did work.

The URL, data, and success attributes were changed to match the page needs.

The line that fires the error is `$.ajax({` I know that means that the whole function has a problem.

Here is the non working function

```
function ajaxFunction(){

var Fname = document.getElementById("FName").value;
var Lname = document.getElementById("LName").value;              
var BirthDate = document.getElementById("BirthDate").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var Pass = document.getElementById("Pass").value;


$.ajax({
    url: "ProHost.php",
    data: { FName:Fname, LName:LName, BirthDate:BirthDate, Email:email, Pass:Pass },
    type: "GET",
    //cache: false,
    async:false,
    success : function (result) {
        console.log("Request sent");

        var result=trim(result);

        $("#demo").hide();

        if(result == 'correct'){
            console.log(result);
            location.assign("/e-Party/HostAcountPage.php");
        }else{
            console.log(result);
            $("#demo").html("You are now registered $FName  $LName , please sign-in ");
        }
    }
});

}
```

here is the working call:

```
var Email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
var Pass = document.getElementById("Pass").value;


console.log( Email + '| | ' + Pass);

$.ajax({
        url: "Process.php",
        data: { Email:Email, Pass:Pass },
        type: "POST",
        //cache: false,
        async:false,
        success : function (result) {
            console.log("Request sent");

            var result=trim(result);
            $("#flash").hide();
            if(result == 'correct'){
                //console.log(result);
                location.assign("/e-Party/HostAcountPage.php");
            }else{
                console.log(result);
                $("#errorMessage").html(result + "<br><a href='../NewHost/NewHost.php'> New Host?</a>");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `async:false` is a bad idea. It forces the browser to freeze until it recieves a network response.

Comment: "I'm changing from using vanilla ajax to jQuery and ajax" - why?

Comment: @JanDvorak this is fine as the user cant do anything until the server is finished

Comment: @JanDvorak Because it cleans up my code and improves maintenance time

Comment: Judging from the stack of the error, it seems that you call some `onclick` function somewhere and this is inside of that. Can you show us where that happened?

Comment: @NobleMushtak the user presses a button and then a JS function runs to validate the input then calls the ajax function. The validation works fine and behaves as it should. So I have reason to believe that the script up to this point works.

Comment: Hm...Now that I look at this again, this looks like a bug with the actual jQuery API because the illegal invocation is actually with a function `e()` within the API, not a function you called. I might be wrong, though. It also might be that you don't have an error function when you should, but that would probably mean that you got an error and you should've gotten an `undefined is not a function` error instead.

Comment: @NobleMushtak I added the other **working** call so you could see it

Comment: @NobleMushtak I just tested to see if `post` or `get` made a difference and it didn't

Comment: If the first works and the second doesn't, I have no idea what's wrong. They're very similar. Hope someone else can help you!